# Starting with e and Pi...how do you get to Phi?

Tags: mathematics

No equations...need one line answer only.

No tricks here.. $e$,  $\pi$, $\phi$ are regularly used universal constants.

Here is the one line answer:

> Starting with $e$ and $\pi$ as Fibonacci seeds, do hundred iterations and take the ratio of last two terms to get to $\phi$.

If you want, you can do more to improve accuracy to multiple decimal places.

Comment: No equations please..just one sentence answer..can be elegantly explained in about 15 words or less..

Comment: I am really puzzled by downvotes..puzzle is explicitly stated..very concise..no equations needed..simple understanding of mathematical process is all you need to give the answer!!

Comment: Is this right and can it be expressed in words? $\phi = e^{i \pi / 5} + e^{-i \pi / 5} $

Comment: "A triangle with sides $\phi$, $e$ and $\pi$ has opposite angles approximately $30$, $60$ and $90$ degrees" (unrelated to the previous comment).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-divine-mathematical-relation-between-pi-phi-and-e

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response...just came from long walk..@ Rand..not what I am looking for.. I am surprised that I didn’t get answer in 5 mts...simple process

Comment: Why do always people think in terms of Eulers equation alone when there are many other people around.

Comment: Irrespective of all the downvotes, I feel this is one of the most elegant puzzles I have designed. Idea came in one minute during my walk.

Comment: Feedback on the answer willl be much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah: that's not exact. The ratio of terms from a Fibonacci series oscillates around $phi$ with alternate terms above and below, only being $phi$ at the infinite term.

Comment: Question is how do you get to phi..it willlead to phi as well as 1/phi.

Comment: It's a nice idea though.

Comment: Given the intended answer, this is really just a curious bit of math trivia more than *a puzzle to solve*, isn't it? It's a neat idea, but there's really no path from puzzle statement to solution other than, really, just knowing that the Fibonacci series terms' ratios converge that way. Puzzles should be *forward-solvable* from information given, not merely be something you *recognize* and provide the answer you already knew.

Comment: My reasoning..golden ratio implies a ratio..if reader understands the concept that with any 2 starting seeds and doing Fibonacci process, we will get to phi..it does not matter whether it is e, pi or something. Logical reasoning involved there.. I fully respect different viewpoints

Comment: So, the intended answer is equivalent to "Starting with $e$ and $\pi$, chuck both in the dumpster. Do Fibonacci to get the answer." How very elegant.

Comment: @Bass while I completely agree that the final answer is _not_ as elegant as the  OP postulated, it is generally a good idea to avoid communicating that in a sarcastic manner.

Comment: The intended answer literally isn't correct because it's not exact.

Comment: It will lead to phi as well as its reciprocal..

Answer (score 1):

Answer

> The product of e square and pi cube is approximately equal to six hundred divided by phi cube.

In formula

> $$\pi \approx \bigg(\frac{600}{(e\phi)^2}\bigg)^{1/3}$$
> EDIT: $$e^2\pi^3 \approx \frac{600}{\phi^2}$$

Found @

> https://quarksdivided.wordpress.com/pi-e-phi/

Comment: Not the one I am looking for..you start with e and pi..end up with phi

Comment: @UVC Is it fine now?

Comment: No..you start with e and Pi and end up with Phi..that process can be stated in one sentence

Comment: This is accurate only to 3 decimal places.

Comment: @Gareth..if we are thinking on the same lines, it should be lot more accurate after 20 steps or so...let me do some quick calculations and will get back to you